# Array Element to Interface Property

Tags: typescript

I would like to take a [`ReadonlyArray<string>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/commit/cac3a32513d2f06cbf1d7da0e34b4df571fe472b) and convert it's elements to an `interface`. That is, from the example below, I'd like to take the `props` array and *synthesize* `Props` interface (the actual type of the `Props` properties are irrelevant to me).

```js
// Given
const props: ReadonlyArray<string> = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];

// Output
interface Props {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
}
```

Perhaps another approach would be to start with the `Props` interface and then *get* the `props` array. Though based on this [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13267#issuecomment-270251290) from a TypeScript developer it seems that is an explicit non-goal of the project.

Comment: You couldn't do that because the type `ReadonlyArray<string>` doesn't provide any information about what the contents of that array are. However, you could use a tuple with constant members, e.g. `props: ['a', 'b', 'c'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and convert that to an interface. Would that work for your use case?

Comment: If you gave that as an answer. Explaining both why it won't work but what might work I'd accept that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for TypeScript to understand what a certain type *is*, it has to be described at compile time. But if you start with the type `ReadonlyArray<string>`, it can only know that `props` contains some strings, and little else (it could be empty, there could be duplicates, etc.) There's no way for the compiler to get from `ReadonlyArray<string>` to `{ a: number, b: number, c: number }` because it could just as easily become almost other type. The closest you could get is `Record<string, number>`, but that's not terribly satisfying.

I'd recommend defining a union type for your keys, like this:

```
type PropKeys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type Props = Record<PropKeys, number>;

const props: ReadonlyArray<PropKeys> = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
const numbers: Props = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}
```

This is the easiest and most natural way to approach this problem.

However, if a union is out of the question for some reason, and you absolutely *must* use an array, you can type the array as a fixed-length tuple with each element being constant type (or union of constant types), so that the compiler can dissect / analyze it and give you back a reconstructed type you're looking for.

```
const props: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
// In TS 3.4 (not yet released at time of writing)
// const props = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

type Props = Record<typeof props[number], number>;
const numbers: Props = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}
```